# Parsing strings that contain time values to a DateTime value

Tags: c#, datetime

I have strings likes this:

```
' 630AM' , '1234PM' , '1000  '
```

These are the values saved in my Database.

And I want to parse them to a date time format, the Date part I don't care, can append a dummy date.
One way is to just have a bunch of if-else and string processing commands to solve it but I feel like we should some how be able to use `DateTime.TryParseExact` and do it in a cleaner way.

What do you suggest to be done along those lines?

Comment: Do these times have any standard formats? You are really going to have a hard time with this otherwise. `TryParseExact` only works if you know the format: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Michael_B : Thanks, What do you mean by "having standard formats" ? The sample ones I posted are the samples I showed above. Data is coming in like those.

Comment: Standard formats meaning they same 3-4 options come in every time. '####AM' or ' ###AM' or '####  ' or ' ###  '?

Comment: @Michael_B : yes, that's all of different formats of it I saw in the DB.

Comment: Do the ones with blanks in the 'AM/PM' space mean they are military time?

Comment: @Michael_B : Great you noticed that...Yes Sir! Military time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would handle these:

```
public DateTime convert(string date)
{
    int hour = int.Parse(date.Substring(0, 2));
    int minute = int.Parse(date.Substring(2, 2));
    if (hour < 12 && date.Substring(4, 2) == "PM")
    {
        hour = hour + 12;
    }

    return new DateTime(2014, 1, 10, hour, minute, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I also wrote something like this: DateTime.TryParseExact(sampleTime, formats, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces , out result);  and then for that formats params gave it these values "hhmmtt", "hhmm"   currently testing both yours and mine